# Struggling with gettng Visual Studio Code to display Console.Writeline() in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code

I have Ubuntu 20.04 install on a VirtualBox VM on my MacBook Pro.
following the instructions from:
[Ubuntu Visual Studio Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio-code)
I used the Software tool in Ubuntu to install Visual Studio Code, .NetCore SDK and .NET Runtime 5.0.  I then Launched Visual Studio, Open a Folder that I created under my $HOME directory.  Open VSCode Terminal and Typed:  dotnet new console

A new project was created with a Program.cs file without errors.

```
using System;

namespace Stake_pool
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

I then typed: dotnet run

No Hello World was generated.  I just got returned to my prompt.  No errors were generated.

I am not sure about how to get Visual Studio to function properly in Ubuntu, after installing the core code and supporting framework.

Please help to get this going, if possible.

Comment: Did you write the code that does the `Console.Writeline()? You say you just did `dotnet new console` and then `dotnet run` - did you edit the source before doing so? Did you open the source at all? The default behavior of an empty console app is just to exit without doing anything.

Comment: @Ken,  Yes, I opened the code and noticed thath the Program.cs was already filled-in with code to generate "Hello World".  I updated my post to show the existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with the `dotnet` tool, here's a [github thread on the issue](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/23616).

A workaround is to run `dotnet` on the `.dll` file output, in your case that would be `dotnet ./bin/Debug/net5.0/Stake_pool.dll`

Or, if you are using vs code you can press ctrl+F5 to run the `.dll` file, which will print the output.